# How to display RadioButton unchecked without seeing the unchecking operation?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I have 2 separate layout files:

[image]

The first one contains 3 radio buttons (no RadioGroup used). The user has to choose the correct answer. After checking an option, when the user clicks the button, I hide the Layout1 and display the Layout2 with the result. When the user clicks the button again, I hide Layout2 and display Layout1. The problem is that the radio button remains checked.

What I have tried, is to use:

```
rb2.isChecked = false
```

When I click the button the second time, before displaying again Layout1, the radio button is unchecked but the problem is that the unchecking operation is displayed. How can I display the radio button unchecked by default, without seeing the unchecking operation?

Comment: Maybe this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42593726/13121971

Comment: @UrbanR Thanks, but it doesn't. I'm not using a RadioGroup. I have my own logic for the radio buttons.

Comment: @UrbanR I said I should to try to use `rb2.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()`, and it worked. No RadioGroup involved. Thank you so much man.